# DST Morocco, a way to trick NTP server

Tags: ntp, ubuntu-14.04

From several years Morocco have been using GMT without DST, in the past years, our government reactivated the use of DST.

In the first years, the DST was a mess, different periods, starts, ends, so Microsoft tried to release some patches, they were available very late, and in some years, the patches were not public and we had to contact Microsoft directly.

From this year, Morocco DST is same than european one, except that Morocco will revert to GMT during the month of Ramadan and move again to DST after it.
As Ramadan is the nineth month in the moon/hijri calendar, there is no way to have a timezone that will change every year and calculate the changes of DST/GMT.

#### Our problem :

We have 2003 active directory, a third of our LAN with Ubuntu Desktop, the connection with AD is done with centrify. We have also many computers, servers outside AD, and we have almost a hundred of network equipements, switches, routers, firewalls, appliances. We have a Linux NTP server.

In GMT all work fine, AD controllers get their time from Linux NTP server, other equipements and no AD ones get also their time from Linux NTP server.

In DST mode, there is many problems, and as my colleagues are stubborn, they don't understand NTP, and they always force the use of point number 1 :

1. Remove NTP config from AD controllers, trick their clock to GMT+1 while their timezone is still GMT.

   In this scheme, the clock is no more accurate, the new clock operate in Windows AD environment only. For Linux computers, even they are members of AD, we must install NTP daemon and add our DC in it's configuration

   Information System divided like a civial war, a part with DST without accurate clock; a part with accurate clock without DST, troubleshooting, tracking logs almost impossible.
2. Leave NTP config on AD controllers, patch the Information System

   It's impossible because there is no such crazy clever patch

   Even I find a patch it won't be available for all products in our Information System, and moreover the patch must have the 2015 version
3. Leave NTP config on AD controllers, change timezone to GMT+1 like WAT

   Very hard to do it, even in 2003 AD, there is no way to do it from GPO !

   Even it is possible, with Ramadan, we have to revert the whole changes to GMT again, and to activate changes once again after Ramadan
4. Filling a petition to the Moroccan government, asking them to leave DST time unchanged in Ramadan, and establishing a decree changing work hours from (9h00 to 15h00 GMT mode) to (10h00 to 16h00 DST mode)

*I am hoping that you will help me to make the 5th scenario possible :*

5. Absolutely no changes in the Information System, apart tricking our Linux NTP server (Ubuntu 14.04) , making it giving its clients the (universal time + 1) instead of (universal time)

   This scenario will require one change, the clock will be accurate while the Information System will have the DST time by staying in GMT timezone

Comment: Can you just create 2 NTP servers? One with each time zone you need, then configure clients to get time from appropriate server...

Comment: The timezone data I have show that DST began on 29th March, will end on 13th June, resume on 18th July, and end again on 25th October. Is this correct?

Comment: yes it's correct, our problem is Ramadan period changes from year to year, but from this year Moroccan DST will be the same as the European one, it will start from last sunday in March till last sunday in October, except in Ramadan we will have to remove DST and revert to GMT

Comment: Hi jlehtinen, NTP servers provide always universal time to their clients, and not the time according their timezone, so even i create ten NTP servers with different timezones, they will provide all of them universal time to their clients, then the clients will adjust their clock according to the universal time provided by NTP server in addition of their own timezones (client timezones)

Comment: Have you looked at Time Zone Editor (tzedit.exe)? You should be able to manually add in the DST changes as necessary if Microsoft is unable to provide a proper hotfix in time for this year. Alternatively, all of the windows hotfixes (including the Morocco updates) are actually done as registry changes. [On top of the keys mentioned in this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/914387), there's additionally a key for the Dyamic DST that may be updated. The easiest way to look at this is to download the hotfix, extract it with 7zip, and look at the Binary.AddBinaryRegKey file.

Comment: thanks for your reply Thebluefish, our Information system contains other equipments than Windows, so it's a global problem related to the not availability of timezone (Casablana) update of the current year for many equipments, i really hope to have a solution, for my question, can you tell me if is it possible to trick our local nt server so it will provide (UTC+1) instead of UTC to its clients?

Comment: Upvoted because of craziness :) I'm happy I don't have to manage that! PS: Don't do 5, it makes systems think UTC is something it's not and that will likely break SSL.

Answer (score 8):

The problem with tricking the computers is that, while the *clock* will appear correct, the *actual times* stored in the system will be one hour wrong. Eventually you will get a timezone update for your operating system, if it is still supported, and then the time errors will appear.

This is how you deal with timezone updates generally (the right way):

For Linux systems, including Linux based NTP servers, you don't need to do anything except to ensure that the `tzdata` package is kept up to date. This is always updated as far in advance of DST changes as is practical, as [it is maintained by the IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones). In fact, it already accounts for Ramadan in 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019... I didn't look any farther.

For Windows systems the issue is more complicated. Microsoft have a poor history of distributing timezone changes in a timely manner, and particularly with Morocco, where [in 2014 it distributed a hotfix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2974661) for the Ramadan DST change [three weeks *after* Ramadan started](http://blogs.technet.com/b/dst2007/archive/2014/07/24/updates-available-for-morocco-dst-ramadan-exception-in-2014.aspx)! In any case, at the moment [you should have correct time until Ramadan](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3048015) if you have applied the [December 2014 cumulative time zone update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3013410). Microsoft states they will distribute a hotfix to account for 2015 Ramadan at a future time. Especially with Microsoft's terrible track record at distributing these updates, you should try to push them out as soon as they are available.

If Microsoft have not made a hotfix available before Ramadan, I would work around the problem by using a GPO to change the system timezone on all Windows systems to GMT, and then change it back at the end of Ramadan. As noted above, Linux systems do not need any correction.

Finally, note that Server 2003 is going end of life and will not receive further updates. This means it won't be possible in any reasonable manner to update its idea of daylight saving time. You should decommission any remaining XP and 2003 systems as soon as possible (not only for that reason, but for all the other reasons).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, honestly i know all this, unfortunately even we have some computers  and servers in Windows 7, 8, 8.1, 2008R2, 2012R2, the majority of our information system is still in XP and 2003 servers, including our active directory, so i don't think that a hotfix will be available for those systems, i tried also to change timezone via GPO in vain, this scenario isn't supported in Windows 2003

Comment: and finally like i said it's not just about computers and servers, there is also lot of switches, routers, firewalls, it's really a big big mess, and according your answer about tricking the timezone, i agree with what you said, but i will add, in this scheme i will force all our information system to use GMT, then i will trick the NTP if it's possible, and as the GMT have no DST, there is no fear about the clock will change

Comment: You _can_ just run everything on GMT all the time, and ignore DST (except maybe for your desktops). This is also a common best practice, and it avoids this sort of problem.

Comment: unfortunately it's not possible,our company operate in a domain where changes made to country DST must be followed, also, just for example, not changing clock disturb users in their mailboxes,also it's not logical for us to display GMT while our staff work following DST

Comment: You don't need to use the same timezone on your servers and your work computers. If it's causing a problem, then don't do it.

Comment: Hi gparent, there is a misunderstanding about how NTP servers works, NTP server provide only "universal time" to its clients, so you can be in Japan and use a NTP server located in brazil, nigeria, india, france or elsewhere in the world, once the client receive the universal clock, it will display clock according its local timezone, so the problem isn't about different timezones in servers/clients

Comment: gparent-- the problem it's about the lack of an updated timezone (Casablanca) of the current year for all the equipments, servers, computers, switches, routers, firewalls, appliances and so on ....only tricking NTP server making it deliver "universal time+1" instead of "universal time" will solve the problem, otherwise i have to deal with timezone updates for different equipments, it's impossible

Comment: @hiboujid: You have correctly pointed out above that NTP uses UTC always.  This is not something you can change.  Therefore option 3 in your original post is your only viable option to maintain accurate times on your clients.  I would suggest two things to try there: 1. Press your Microsoft representative to lobby Microsoft to get an accurate DST patch out in a reasonable timeframe. 2. Investigate getting someone (possibly Microsoft or one of their partners) to produce a custom timezone patch for you.  Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your proposition, the problem is the request to Microsoft will have to take place every year due the change of the position of Ramadan in the calendar till the year where Ramadan leave the DST period ... so i know my options are very limited, but i hope to avoid negotiating with Microsoft every year.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has released a hotfix:  https://support.microsoft.com/kb/3062740.  There is a 2003 patch.

For Windows operating systems that are no longer supported, if you do not have customizations to your time zones using TZEdit, you can simply export/import the registry key for the time zone information and it will work on all Windows platforms.  This can be done through a group policy.  (May require a restart).

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones]
```

The real solution would be for Morocco to appoint/elect representatives that are not incompetent regarding how a business should operate.

On a fundamental level, the usefulness of DST is questionable (most countries don't use it), and it only works properly when it is applied consistently and predictably.  Countries like Brazil, Israel, and Morocco that think they can cook up a pig's breakfast of different DST dates all over the place as if this were some kind of game they can tinker with are incompetent.  Sometimes there just is not a one ring to rule them all silver bullet magic solution for incompetence.